# FLutter Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"150","method":"resume","params":{"isolateId":"isolates/3252146049990519"}}

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator

I'm getting a strange error when debugging my flutter app in Android Studio 2021.2.1 patch 1

```
Lost connection to device.
Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"150","method":"resume","params": 
{"isolateId":"isolates/3252146049990519"}}
```

The error is throw when the app hits a error in the code, in this case it expects a image but null is returned.

It's only when I debug on a Android emulator with the following setup

Pixel 5
Android API 32 x86_64
RAM: 1536 MB
VM Heap: 2000 MB
Internal storage 16 GB

I've tried restarting and using API 31, which also fails. When using API 33 it doesn't even startup.

Here's the complete dump of the debug log
´

```
                     ^
    [log] Environment: TEST
    [log] Initializing AppModel
    [log] Loading experiences
    I/EngineFactory( 3075): Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not available
    [log] params: ?distance=100000000&latitude=37.4218708&longitude=-122.0841223
    [log] Number of experiences parsed: 6
    [log] Image null is null
    [log] Image null is null
    [log] Fetching https://explorum-api.azurewebsites.net/files/0av3f5rl.jxo.jpg
    [log] Image null is null
    [log] Image null is null
    D/EGL_emulation( 3075): app_time_stats: avg=1455.99ms min=119.60ms max=2792.38ms count=2
    F/libc    ( 3075): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 
    0x763d55955ff8 in tid 3144 (1.ui), pid 3075 (dk.explorum)
    *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint:  
 
 
 
 'google/sdk_gphone64_x86_64/emulator64_x86_64_arm64:12/S2B2.211203.006/8015633:userdebug/dev-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'x86_64'
    Timestamp: 2022-07-29 05:32:24.888859600+0000
    Process uptime: 0s
    Cmdline: dk.explorum
    pid: 3075, tid: 3144, name: 1.ui  >>> dk.explorum <<<
    uid: 10148
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x763d55955ff8
Cause: stack pointer is close to top of stack; likely stack overflow.
    rax 0000000000000000  rbx 0000763ec8eaf380  rcx 0000000000000010  rdx 0000000000000000
    r8  0000000000000000  r9  0000000000000000  r10 000000000000000c  r11 0000763d56dd8c20
    r12 0000763d491615c0  r13 0000763d49161610  r14 0000000000000400  r15 000000000000000c
    rdi 00007640708116c0  rsi 0000000000000400
    rbp 0000763d55956140  rsp 0000763d55956000  rip 0000764070775945
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000049945  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::allocate(unsigned long, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, bool)+5) (BuildId: 0bac1e57b41382f7871677ca544454ea)
      #01 pc 000000000004a029  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (scudo_malloc+25) (BuildId: 0bac1e57b41382f7871677ca544454ea)
      #02 pc 0000000000044da7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (malloc+23) (BuildId: 0bac1e57b41382f7871677ca544454ea)
      #03 pc 0000000001ae6d7c  /data/app/~~C3q5___YEWVKDLu7Ori-eA==/dk.explorum-e91kKmo5qCYYp9knhk9UmQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9831e46e3db7a12bfe5937dce87e97ddfeb00cd8)
      #04 pc 0000000001a8bd9e  /data/app/~~C3q5___YEWVKDLu7Ori-eA==/dk.explorum-e91kKmo5qCYYp9knhk9UmQ==/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 9831e46e3db7a12bfe5937dce87e97ddfeb00cd8)



Lost connection to device.
Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"47","method":"resume","params":{"isolateId":"isolates/3781439660544527"}}
...
```